# I want to stop non-alphabetical characters been put into the input

Tags: javascript, validation, alphabetical, letters

Currently I have a piece of javascript that stops the form been submitted if the inputs are empty but I want to make the script also stop non-alphabetical characters been put in too.

Here is the script

`function checkFormWhole(){

```
        //var theForm = document.getElementById(id);
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        var letnums = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
        var theForm = document.getElementById("bookingForm");


            if (theForm.customerType.value == ""){
                alert("Please choose a customer type");
                return false;

                        }
            else if (theForm.customerType.value == "nonCorp" && theForm.forename.value == "") {
                    alert("Please Enter A Forename");
                    return false;

            }
            else if (theForm.customerType.value == "nonCorp" && theForm.surname.value == "") {
                    alert("Please Enter A Surname");
                    return false;

            }
            else if (checked == 0) {
                    alert("Please Choose An Event To Book");
                    return false;

            }
            else if (theForm.customerType.value == "corp" && theForm.companyName.value == "") {
                    alert("Please Enter A Company Name");
                    return false;

            }
```

where i want the validation --->

```
else if (theForm.customerType.value == "nonCorp" && theForm.forename.value != (letters)  /*|| theForm.customerType.surname.value.match != (letters)*/) {
                        alert("Please Enter A Forename Containing ONLY letters");
                        return false;
                }


                        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the pattern as below.

```
var str = '123456';
var str2 = 'abcdEFG';
var patt = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
// Contains non alphabet chars
if(patt.test(str) === true) {
    console.log('Your input includes invalid characters')
}

// Contains alphabet chars only
if(patt.test(str2) === false) {
    console.log('Your input includes valid characters')
}
```

You can simplify this but the example above has enough for you to be able to add the functionality you need.

Add your example to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and if you have any problems, people can help you easier.

Comment: Is there a way I can make this work with the code I already have within the function I have created.

Comment: add the patt variable to your function and replace `theForm.forename.value != (letters)` with `patt.test(theForm.forename.value) === true`